# How do I get an HTTP status code from TTransport exceptions?

Tags: c#, thrift

I'm using a thrift HttpClient (C#) to make web requests to a web server I've set up, and if that server returns something other than 200 (or 202 I imagine), my request throws a TTransport exception.

I'd like to respond to this exception based on the specific status code returned, but I don't see anything that exposes the status code in the exception's interface. Have I missed something? I know the exception message contains the status code, but I'd rather not have to parse that message to get at the status code.

Comment: That's an interesting question. The typical use case is to abstract away the details of the underlying transport in order to make it (or better: keep it) interchangeable. That's why all the dirty details are returned by means of the more abstract concept of an TTransportException. May I ask what the purpose behind your question is, what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: If I get a 404 error, I want my app to report that the user that the server is down, and none of the app's functionality will be working until the server is back up. If it's a 500 error, I want to report that the server has a problem dealing with the specific command just issued. 

I don't _need_ to be that detailed in the message I'm displaying to the user, and the error log contains the status code because I'm outputting the exception message there, so I could live with this state of affairs.I had just thought that HTTPClient might have properties specific to its implementation of TTransport

Comment: Have you tried to check the `Type` field of the `TransportException`? In case of an 404 this is set to `EndOfFile`. In case of other errors I get different errors, e.g. `Unknown` or even `TProtocolException`, depending on what protocol I use. Last resort would be to check the message text for some keywords, but that's a bit ugly. Would any of the above solve the issue?

Comment: Is checking for EndOfFile to deduce a 404 something I can rely on for future versions of Thrift?

Comment: I'd not rely on that, as the exact cause of a broken transport medium may have various reasons. It is not necessarily a 404 condition, but it can indicate a certain likelihood for a 404 when HTTP transport is used.

Comment: ... and additoinally, you don't have to know. Knowing the difference between a 404 and a 403.2 or a for any other reason broken connection seems not to add that much value to the application. It all boils down to "Service unreachable" and that's typically everything the user want's to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server encounters an processing error, the recommended method is not throwing a HTTP 500. Instead, the server should signal this by means of an exception. Consider the following Thrift IDL:

```
exception MyProcessingError
{
  1: string reason
  2: string errorDetails
  3: string recommendedAction
}

service FooBar {
  void ProcessPayments( 1: double amount; 2: string receiver) 
  throws (1: MyProcessingError mpe)
}
```

Similar to args and struct fields, multiple exception types can be declared. The client can catch these exceptions as usual:

```
try
{
    client.ProcessPayments( 47.11, "Dagobert");
}
catch (MyProcessingError e)
{
    // process exception
}
```

**Remarks**

- The server may only throw exceptions that are declared in the IDL for
  the particular call.
- Furthermore, `oneway` calls never return any value, thus no
  exceptions either.